# Minimum distance requirement between service drop cables

Tags: electrical

Is there a minimum distance requirement between service drop cables?
I live in orange county california.
Thank you

Comment: I take it this is about the horizontal clearance required between two service drops?

Comment: Correct. Between the hot cables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

### As far as I can tell, there is no minimum

Based on my reading of [SCE's Electrical Service Requirements](https://www.sce.com/sites/default/files/custom-files/Electrical%20Service%20Requirements%20(ESR).pdf), there is no minimum horizontal clearance between overhead service drops.